# Why my validating data doesn't make accurate guesses

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

After splitting the dataset and training the model, I have two almost identical codes: one to make predictions of training data and another to make predictions of the validating data. The training data code makes good enough predictions, but the validating code makes the same prediction each time. It would be one thing if my model just didn't produce accurate results, but this "same guess" situation happens each time I run it.

Example:

```
 [47.         50.86761856]
 [38.         50.86761856]
 [57.         50.86761856]
 [52.         50.86761856]
 [34.         50.86761856]
 [59.         50.86761856]
 [28.         50.86761856]
```

The network part:

```
X_train, X_validate, Y_train, Y_validate = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2) 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'swish', input_shape =(145662,))) 
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

baselogger = BaseLogger(stateful_metrics = ['loss'])
cp = ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', monitor='mae', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, 
save_weights_only=True, mode='min', period=1)

optimizer_choice = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0005) 
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer_choice, metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks=[cp, baselogger]) 
model.summary()

score1 = model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train, verbose=0) 
print("Training Set results: " + str(score1))

score2 = model.evaluate(X_validate, Y_validate, verbose = 0)
print("Validating Set Results: " + str(score2))
```

Here is the predicting part of the code:

```
trainingResults=[None]*29
trainingResults=np.array(trainingResults)
i=0
while i<29:
  X_test=X_train[i]
  y_real=Y_train[i]
  y_guess=model.predict(np.array([X_test]))
  y_guess=y_guess.flatten() 
  pair=[y_real,y_guess[0]]#0 to i
  trainingResults[i]=pair
  i+=1
trainingResults=np.stack(trainingResults)


validatingResults=[None]*8
validatingResults=np.array(validatingResults)
i=0
while i<8:
  X_val_test=X_validate[i]
  y_val_real=Y_validate[i]
  y_val_guess=model.predict(np.array([X_val_test]))
  y_val_guess=y_guess.flatten() 
  pair=[y_val_real,y_val_guess[0]] #0 to i
  validatingResults[i]=pair
  i+=1
validatingResults=np.stack(validatingResults)
print("Validating results" + str(validatingResults))
```

***Update
With the validatingResults=np.array(validatingResults) commented out, this is my print:

```
Training Set results: [11.32441234588623, 11.32441234588623]
Validating Set Results: [8.808736801147461, 8.808736801147461]
Validating results[[37.         46.50443268]
 [49.         46.50443268]
 [55.         46.50443268]
 [60.         46.50443268]
 [47.         46.50443268]
 [38.         46.50443268]
 [51.         46.50443268]
 [35.         46.50443268]]
[46.504433]
```

Another update:)
This is without the np.array commented out

```
Training Set results: [9.697625160217285, 9.697625160217285]
Validating Set Results: [16.113449096679688, 16.113449096679688]
Validating results[[51.         41.37454605]
 [56.         41.37454605]
 [58.         41.37454605]
 [30.         41.37454605]
 [63.         41.37454605]
 [38.         41.37454605]
 [59.         41.37454605]
 [60.         41.37454605]]
[41.374546]
```

Comment: did you try changing your test set to different one?

Comment: Yes, each time it is a different predicted number, but it's that same predicted number for all the x_val_test used to make predictions off

Comment: remove this line `validatingResults=np.array(validatingResults)` (not make it an np.array) and try again

Comment: That didn't work, either. What is the thought process for trying that, though?

Comment: Because np.array underneath may share entries with same values as optimisation,. Can you update your question with the pritn output?

Comment: Yes, I just updated it:)

Comment: It is a fact that in some cases this can happen. Although the model is trained well, individual predictions very close might give exactly same result or very close results. Try very different values, ie values where the real output differs by wide margin, and see what you get

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your help!:)